# Post reordering in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, post

I`m New to wordpress.In my page the post is displayed using calling the template.But now I want reorder some posts in this page.Following is my code ,which is used to display the post.How can I edit this code to reorder some post titles.Please help me.

```
 <?php 
/*
Template Name: Portfolio Page
*/
?>

<?php 
$et_ptemplate_settings = array();
$et_ptemplate_settings = maybe_unserialize( get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_ptemplate_settings',true) );

$fullwidth = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_fullwidthpage'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_fullwidthpage'] : false;
$et_ptemplate_showtitle = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showtitle'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showtitle'] : false;
$et_ptemplate_showdesc = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showdesc'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_showdesc'] : false;
$et_ptemplate_detect_portrait = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_detect_portrait'] ) ? (bool) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_detect_portrait'] : false;

$gallery_cats = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_gallerycats'] ) ? (array) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_gallerycats'] : array();
$et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage'] ) ? (int) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage'] : 12;

$et_ptemplate_portfolio_size = isset( $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_imagesize'] ) ? (int) $et_ptemplate_settings['et_ptemplate_imagesize'] : 2;

$et_ptemplate_portfolio_class = '';
if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 1 ) $et_ptemplate_portfolio_class = ' et_portfolio_small';
if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 ) $et_ptemplate_portfolio_class = ' et_portfolio_large';
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="clearfix<?php if($fullwidth) echo(' fullwidth');?>">
    <div id="left-area">
        <?php get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs','page'); ?>
        <div id="entries">
            <div class="entry post clearfix">
                <?php get_template_part('loop','page'); ?>

                <div id="et_pt_portfolio_gallery" class="clearfix<?php echo $et_ptemplate_portfolio_class; ?>">
                    <?php $gallery_query = '';
                    $portfolio_count = 1;
                    $et_open_row = false;
                    if ( !empty($gallery_cats) ) $gallery_query = '&cat=' . implode(",", $gallery_cats);
                    else echo '<!-- gallery category is not selected -->'; ?>
                    <?php 
                        $et_paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : get_query_var( 'paged' );
                    ?>
                    <?php query_posts("showposts=$et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage&paged=" . $et_paged . $gallery_query); ?>
                    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php $width = 260;
                        $height = 170;

                        if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 1 ) {
                            $width = 140;
                            $height = 94;
                            $et_portrait_height = 170;
                        }
                        if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 ) $et_portrait_height = 315;
                        if ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 ) {
                            $width = 430;
                            $height = 283;
                            $et_portrait_height = 860;
                        }                       

                        $et_auto_image_detection = false;
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) && $et_ptemplate_detect_portrait ) {
                            $wordpress_thumbnail = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
                            $wordpress_thumbnail_url = $wordpress_thumbnail->guid;

                            if ( et_is_portrait($wordpress_thumbnail_url) ) $height = $et_portrait_height;
                        }

                        $titletext = get_the_title();
                        $et_portfolio_title = get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_portfolio_title',true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_portfolio_title',true) : get_the_title();
                        $et_videolink = get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_videolink',true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID,'et_videolink',true) : '';

                        $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,'',$titletext,$titletext,true,'et_portfolio');
                        $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];

                        if ( $et_ptemplate_detect_portrait && $thumbnail["use_timthumb"] && et_is_portrait($thumb) ) {
                            $height = $et_portrait_height;
                        } ?>

                        <?php if ( $portfolio_count == 1 || ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 && (!$fullwidth && ($portfolio_count+1) % 2 == 0) ) || ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 && (($portfolio_count+1) % 2 == 0) ) ) {
                            $et_open_row = true; ?>
                            <div class="et_pt_portfolio_row clearfix">
                        <?php } ?>

                            <div class="et_pt_portfolio_item">
                                    <?php if ($et_ptemplate_showtitle) { ?>
                                        <h2 class="et_pt_portfolio_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $et_portfolio_title; ?></a></h2>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <div class="et_pt_portfolio_entry<?php if ( $height == $et_portrait_height ) echo ' et_portrait_layout'; ?>">
                                        <div class="et_pt_portfolio_image<?php if ($et_videolink <> '') echo ' et_video'; ?>">
                                            <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, ''); ?>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="et_pt_portfolio_overlay"></span></a>

                                            <a class="et_portfolio_zoom_icon <?php if ($et_videolink <> '') echo 'et_video_lightbox'; else echo('fancybox'); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"<?php if ($et_videolink == '') echo ' rel="portfolio"'; ?> href="<?php if ($et_videolink <> '') echo esc_url($et_videolink); else echo($thumbnail['fullpath']); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Zoom in','Aggregate'); ?></a>
                                            <a class="et_portfolio_more_icon" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Read more','Aggregate'); ?></a>
                                        </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_image -->
                                    </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_entry -->
                                    <?php if ($et_ptemplate_showdesc) { ?>
                                        <p><?php truncate_post(90); ?></p>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_item -->

                        <?php if ( ($et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 && !$fullwidth && $portfolio_count % 2 == 0) || ( $et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 3 && ($portfolio_count % 2 == 0) ) ) {
                            $et_open_row = false; ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php if ( ($et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 2 && $fullwidth && $portfolio_count % 3 == 0) || ($et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 1 && !$fullwidth && $portfolio_count % 3 == 0) || ($et_ptemplate_portfolio_size == 1 && $fullwidth && $portfolio_count % 5 == 0) ) { ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                            <div class="et_pt_portfolio_row clearfix">
                            <?php $et_open_row = true; ?>
                        <?php } ?>

                    <?php $portfolio_count++; 
                    endwhile; ?>
                        <?php if ( $et_open_row ) { 
                            $et_open_row = false; ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="page-nav clearfix">
                            <?php if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
                            else { ?>
                                 <?php get_template_part('includes/navigation'); ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .entry -->
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php if ( $et_open_row ) { 
                            $et_open_row = false; ?>
                            </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php get_template_part('includes/no-results'); ?>
                    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                    <?php if ( $et_open_row ) { 
                        $et_open_row = false; ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .et_pt_portfolio_row -->
                    <?php } ?>
                </div> <!-- end #et_pt_portfolio_gallery -->

            </div> <!-- end .entry -->

        </div> <!-- end #entries -->
    </div> <!-- end #left-area -->

    <?php if (!$fullwidth) get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You should ask on Elegant Theme's forum. You should have access to it if you bought the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant section of the template is this line here;

```
<?php query_posts("showposts=$et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage&paged=" . $et_paged . $gallery_query); ?>
```

The `query_posts` method is used to alter the main Wordpress Loop.  In this case you have a list of parameters all fused together and separated with the '&' character but if you look in [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) you can also pass an array into query_posts() which is easier to modify as it can be laid out and formatted like so (note `showposts` has been deprecated in favour of `posts_per_page`);

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => $et_ptemplate_gallery_perpage, 'paged' => $et_paged . $gallery_query, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>
```

You would choose your orderby options by looking at the [Codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).